# Checking if caps lock is on in react-native

Tags: react-native

Currently, I only use Android's

```
event.isCapsLockOn(){}
```

to check if caps lock is on and then prompt the user if it is.

Is there a built in prop/command in react native to do this, so I can do both in Android and iOS?